# Android Studio project not creating with Error:Cause: invalid bit length repeat

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

actually, initially it was working fine. but suddenly I have created a new project after that it shows this error "Error: Cause: invalid bit length repeat".  I have checked in gradle log "WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask" . and sometimes it shows like this "Error:Cause: org/gradle/cli/SystemPropertiesCommandLineConverter"this is the error I am getting.actually, this type of error is new to me.can you anybody give the solution on this.

Thank you

Comment: Are you doing file compression/ decompression in your program?

Comment: nothing..just i have created new project.after that it shows like that

Comment: Did you update/install JDK/JRE recently?

Comment: i have updated my jdk 1.7 to 1.8

Comment: Try removing the JDK and re-installing the correct version. If you have Android Studio 64-bit, make sure you install JDK 64-bit too.
Let me know if it helps

Comment: Just check if your gradle path is set. Go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle. What is selected in Project level settings?

Comment: "use default graddle wrapper" checked @Aishwarya

Comment: just now i have reinstalled android studio and java too...it's not working #suhayi|Sh

Comment: Create a new project and see if you get same errors

Comment: thank you, boss. actually after reinstalling my setups I didn't create any project.i was just <invalidate and restart> my IDE. so it didn't happen to my project.after creating a new project.now working fine